# Error with npm install : getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND hostname-entry-in-hosts-file at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup

Tags: npm-install, hosts, npm-start, hosts-file

I am facing an issue with npm start

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND prizm-new-luke.pearson.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:71:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'prizm-new-luke.pearson.com'
}

Tried all options like below

============================================

If python2 command not found

Check what python is installed

***which python***

***which python2***

***which python3***

**Then try:-**

brew install pyenv

pyenv install 2.7.18

pyenv global  2.7.18

**After this python2 —version and python3 —version both give results.**

Then try

npm install --python=/Users/VBOSESA/.pyenv/shims/python2 -f -verbose

open ~/.zshrc

Add in the file ***alias python=“~/usr/bin/python3”***

source ~/.zshrc

============================================

npm cache clean

Hosts file update

sudo nano /private/etc/hosts

vim /private/etc/hosts

npm config deleteproxy
npm config deletehttp-proxy
npm config deletehttps-proxy

But no solution

Answer (score 0):

In MAC

Open terminal in admin capabilities
su - Admin_UserName
Admin_Password
 
From the same terminal
Open hosts file to add the entries
sudo nano /private/etc/hosts
 
When I logged in as admin, then only I could see that the hosts file was corrupted

Then cleared of the clutter and everything worked like charm.